# Failed to Load SWC Binary Error in Next.js Development Server

Tags: next.js, dll, hadoop-yarn, swc

[I encountered an issue while running my Next.js project using the yarn run dev command. The error message is as follows in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg52e.png)

Error Details:

Next.js Version: 14.0.3
Local Server: http://localhost:3000
Issue Description:

The error mentions an attempt to load @next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc.
Specifically, it reports a failure in the dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine.
The path to the problematic file is provided (\?\E:\SProject\my-app\node_modules@next\swc-win32-ia32-msvc\next-swc.win32-ia32-msvc.node).
The error message suggests a failure to load the SWC binary for win32/ia32.
Actions Taken:

I have already checked the official documentation related to this error for additional information.
Request for Help:

I am seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully load the SWC binary for win32/ia32 in my Next.js development environment.
Any insights, troubleshooting steps, or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Information:

My development environment is using Yarn (yarn run dev), and the project is located at E:\SProject\my-app.
Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and solved it by uninstalling the 32 bit version of node js and installing the 64 bit version instead.